# How can I render custom HTML in Spree with Deface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, spree

I am replacing some Spree core template code with Deface and it all works well until I try to make it a bit more custom.

```
Deface::Override.new(
    :virtual_path => "spree/shared/_products",
    :replace => "span.price",
    :text => "<%= link_to truncateproduct.display_price + '<span class=\"purchase-suggestion\">BUY NOW</span>', :length => 20), product, :class => 'price selling', :itemprop => \"price\", :title => product.name + ': ' + product.display_price %>",
    :name => "product_price"
)
```

Above I am aiming to make the price text a link, and also include a 'BUY NOW' text wrapped in a span for individual styling purpose.

This renders this way:
`$15.99<span class="purchase-suggestion">BUY NOW</span>`

How can I make Deface evaluate the HTML instead of writing the string?

I have tried doing this in two steps by making two different Deface files, one where I swap the span for the link, and another where I add the span to :insert_bottom. It seems to me it is not possible to use Deface to change the same element twice - is this correct?

---

**Solution**
Thanks for answer and conversation in channel. This is the solution:

```
Deface::Override.new(
    :virtual_path => "spree/shared/_products",
    :replace => "span.price",
    :text => "<%=
                  link_to ('<span>' + product.display_price + '</span> <span class=\"purchase-suggestion\">BUY NOW</span>').html_safe, product,
                  :class => 'price selling',
                  :itemprop => 'price',
                  :title => product.name + ': ' + product.display_price
              %>",
    :name => "product_price"
)
```

`.truncate` was used for no reason, `.html_safe` did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is with truncate. The result is not marked as HTML-safe, so will be subject to the default escaping when used in views, unless wrapped by raw(). Care should be taken if text contains HTML tags or entities, because truncation may produce invalid HTML (such as unbalanced or incomplete tags).

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate